# Doubly Linked List as a class or a technique?

Tags: java

In my Data Structures homework, teacher asks us to: 
"Define List ADT (throughout this document, “list” refers to this list, not to java.util.List) and implement it using a doubly linked list."

I have an interface called `IList<E>`.

Which is the best design choice would you say?:

- Have a `DoublyLinkedList<E>` class that implements `IList<E>`. And have a `List<E>` class that also implements `IList<E>`, which has a field called `list` that instantiates `DoublyLinkedList<E>`. Then perform all class methods using `list`.

or

- Directly have a `List<E>` class that implements `IList<E>`. And set up its inner structure with Double Linked Nodes.

Edit: Next sentence in the homework says: 
Define Priority Queue ADT and implement it using a singly linked list.

This is why I'm even thinking about the first way. I can't implement `IList<E>` for a queue. I can only use an `IList<E>`field to call `SinglyLinkedList<E>` methods. Or else I will apply the second way to this too, but then the queue never deals with a list, which bothers me.  Am I wrong to expect "using a singly linked **approach**" in the wording?

Comment: What is special (w.r.t implementation) in `List`?

Comment: From what I understand, you will just have one implementation(`DoublyLinkedList`) of `IList`

Comment: @user7 Nothing's special but it completely hides the implementation details (int this case: doublylinked) from the client.

Comment: In that case, the client must be depending on `IList`

Comment: Please explain what is ADT. Abstract data type?

Comment: Also, which operations do you have to implement?

Comment: Yes, ADT is abstract data type. The operation I need to implement are based on the homework actually but just for reusability i tried to implement all of the basic methods.